# CakePHP model behaviors in Symfony2 + Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to have behaviors in Symfony 2 entities, like in CakePHP? I'll try to explain what I need:

In some of my entities, I need to store who created or updated the record, when it was created or updated, at which company does it belongs and at which season does it belongs.

All these data is stored in the session, and I want to add it to the entity "magically", without adding these fields in the controller. With CakePHP I can create SeasonBehavior, mark some models/entities as they use the SeasonBehavior and when I persist a record from an entity marked with the SeasonBehavior the seasonId is updated.

Is it possible to do the same with Symfony2 and Doctrine 2? And if it's possible, do you know any tutorial or documentation explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create listener on your Persist action to do such things. Read the manual here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: Ok, so I must create a listener, and mark the classes (implementing an interface, for example) and then update the data, isn't it?